# (Blender 2.79) Stars moving around quickly when camera moves

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

So, let me get straight to the point. I'm trying to make a Titanic sinking animation. I added reflections (mirror) to the ocean (plane mesh), and when I animate the camera moving and rotating, the stars start moving around quickly, which is just irritating.

Answers to questions you'll probably ask:

- Why 2.79? Because my PC sucks, can't run 2.8+
- Render Engine? Internal (aka Blender Render), Cycles takes too long to render an animation.
- How did you make the stars? Stucci texture, with some tweaks.

Animation here, showing the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yHzA.jpg

Comment: hello, in your video I can't see what you're talking about, your camera is not moveing and neither your stars. Also, are your stars part of a World HDRI?

Comment: I'm not really using a HDRI, the stars were made manually with the stucci texture, they serve as a background, along with the sky itself. And also, yes, my camera is moving, so are the stars in the water reflection, maybe turn up the brightness and you'll be able to see it.

Comment: are you talking about the reflections? maybe pack your image and share your file (only keep the useful items, not the boat for example)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Ok, I'll share the .blend file later if that isn't a problem to you. I am not able to use my computer right now.

Comment: There is the file, without the ship though. You may notice the camera is with a cube, this is another method I used to see if I could avoid this, but it didn't work too: https://pasteall.org/blend/b28e3ad038f340e5bd7b14dec889c8f1